# Sufficient conditions for an inequality with a log

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

I need to find sufficient conditions so that $x \geq \frac{1}{a-\ln{x}}$ for $a>1$ and $x > 0$.

Is there a way to get a tight solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the condition
$$x> \exp(a)$$
Take the $\log$ and get
$$\log(x)>a$$
Putting everything on the right gives
$$a-\log(x)<0$$
Hence 
$$\frac{1}{a-\log(x)}<0$$
and
$$x\geq\frac{1}{a-\log(x)}$$
is certainly satisfied because $\log(x)$ exists for $x>0$.